# Negative powers in complex expressions like negative powers in real expressions?

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to confirm that $e^{-z ^{-9}} = \frac{z}{(e^{-z})^9} = z(e^{z})^9$ where $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Are you looking at $\exp( - z^{ - 9} )$ or $(e^{ - z} )^{ - 9}$?

Comment: @Gary Ah, I think the former, which explains my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You've made two mistakes.

First, you put a $z$ in the numerator of the fraction, where it should just be a $1$.

Second, remember the notation $a^{b^c}$ implicitly means $a^{(b^c)}$, not $(a^b)^c$.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in the slightest. The true identity is $$e^{-z^{-9}}=\frac1{e^{(1/(z^9))}}$$

which doesn't automatically disprove yours but, well, perhaps my RHS is written in a form which we read the same way, and therefore you should be able to check a few substitutions.